# Microsoft Excel get Count of Distinct Values

Tags: excel, ms-office

I am trying to use excel to get a count of distinct values, the following screenshot will illustrate what I am trying to do. [Data Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/11WLz.png)

Given data in the form on the left column I would like a way to display the occurrences of each distinct value on the right.
I have used the Outline Subtotal grouping to do this but it does not present the data in a form I can work with. I am by all means an Excel novice, any help would be appreciated
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use a pivot Table.  Put the column in both the Rows and Values:

[image]